# Best practice for Laravel global sessions used for site settings

Tags: laravel, global-variables

Previously in procedural php, I had developed a multi-site website where I would store site settings in the database and when a user vists the website I would run:

```
select theme, email, default_language from site where active=1 and url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] limit 1;
```

and the result would be stored in a config session. Then throughout the site, I could use the theme value to load corresponding templates for that site. What would be best practice to do this in Laravel?

Thanks

Comment: When user log in, you are getting their session. You are using that session to get corresponding data from database. If there is more data than session variable(s) should take, cache results from database. Don't forget to clear cache and make another (file, if file driver is used) when DB data was deleted/updated/inserted.

Answer (score 0):

create a config file in **config** folder, You can get values from config files.

Add your configs

```
config('site.locale',$site->lang); //set the local
```

And add another for theme

```
config('site.theme',$site->theme); //set the theme
```

Now you have access to  config values

```
config('site.locale'); //get the language for this site
config('site.theme');  //get the themefor this site
```

Comment: Don't forget your `.env` file for the sensitive stuff!

Comment: I want to give ownership of the site to the client, I didn't to have to make any changes to files. I want them to make any changes via an admin panel, i'll look into @Mahdi, solution. thx